# Why Shallow routing not working in Nextjs?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am using Shallow routing in Next.js to push state to url which not navigate page but it not working as expected.

In the example code below I am visit the home page at url: `localhost:3000`, when I am clicking the button to push state url **without** navigate to `localhost:3000/post/1` but looks like shallow not working, it always redirects me to `localhost:3000/post/1`.

```
const router = useRouter();

const handleClick = () => {
   router.push(`/post/${post.id}`, undefined, { shallow: true });
}

<Button onClick={handleClick}>
   Go to post
</Button>
```

What did I do wrong with shallow routing from the above code?

Answer (score 1):

looking at the caveats of shallow routing [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/shallow-routing#caveats), since path parameters (dynamic routes) are changing the path, this is expected behaviour.